# iOS: can we record landscape video and show what's being recording in real time while the user is holding the iPhone vertically?

Tags: ios, video, camera

iOS: can we record horizontal(landscape) video and show what's being recording in real time while the user is holding the iPhone vertically?

I'm thinking if we force user to take horizontal(landscape) movie, is it feasible?

I'm not sure it's a good idea or not. Just want to know its technical feasibility.

Comment: Sorry but what you mean with horizontal video?

Comment: @elio.d sorry, I mean landscape.

Comment: I would imagine that the camera CCD is oriented with the phone.  In order to take a "landscape" photo you'd have to crop the "portrait" photo.